# Unresolved external symbol on basic function

Tags: c++, lnk2019, lnk

Build error LNK2019 happens when building project with 1 cpp file

```
namespace foo {

    __declspec(dllimport) void Print();

}


void main()
{
    foo::Print();
}
```

foo is defined.

header (in other folder):

```
#pragma once

namespace foo {

    __declspec(dllexport) void Print();

}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl foo::Print(void)" (_*imp*?Print@foo@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main  sb  C:\Users\user\source\repos\foo\sb\Application.obj   1

context if needed: following a VS2017 guide. I don't know if something might have changed.

Comment: Did you add the lib file where foo is implemented to this project?

Comment: @DaveS isn't it supposed to be generated when I build it?

Comment: You say "header (in other folder):" -- so you have 2 folders, one creates a DLL, this one uses the DLL?  The one project creates a lib file, the other project needs to add the path to that created lib file in order to use it.  Just the H file is not enough, you need H + LIB.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: Right.  The compiler GENERATED the lib when you built the DLL, but it's not in a place where your EXE project can find it.

Comment: ***following a VS2017 guide. I don't know if something might have changed.*** No, Creating a dll has been the same for over 20 years. My advice is to start with this Microsoft Tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: *"following a VS2017 guide"*  On the other hand, if you are learning C++, and don't specifically **have to** use VS2017, a lot of other things have changed in the language since 2017. Using the latest version is *strongly* recommended - saves you from asking "Why doesn't this work?" just to get the answer "It does now!".